# how to allow not paypal users to pay via credit card

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I have just opened new sandbox account on paypal, but I cant find the way to allow it to pay via credit card like on the production account.. 
I have found the the way to do it is to go into profile and turn on something called "PayPal Account Optional" but I cant find it in the profile page..

Answer (score 0):

It seems you can find this option here: Profile (in top menu) > My Selling Tools > Website Payment Preferences > PayPal Account Optional section or [direct link](https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/customerprofileweb?cmd=_profile-website-payments)

Comment: Thank you that was what I was looking for, tho seems it was already on but still I don't have the option to pay with credit card :( thanks anyways..

Comment: This option can be overwritten by parameters in API/POST request to PayPal. For example in Express Checkout flow (https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/SetExpressCheckout_API_Operation_NVP/) we can play with SOLUTIONTYPE parameter.